# How to Use the SAXparser to send an XML request and parse the response

Tags: android, xml, saxparser

How to Use the SAXparser to send an XML request and parse the response.I am developing a bookin app using expedia.
XML as BELOW

```
http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?
minorRev=[current minorRev #]
&cid=55505
&apiKey=[xxx-yourOwnKey-xxx]
&customerUserAgent=[xxx]
&customerIpAddress=[xxx]
&locale=en_US
&currencyCode=USD
&xml=
<HotelListRequest>
<city>Seattle</city>
<stateProvinceCode>WA</stateProvinceCode>
<countryCode>US</countryCode>
<arrivalDate>08/01/2012</arrivalDate>
<departureDate>08/03/2012</departureDate>
<RoomGroup>
  <Room>
    <numberOfAdults>2</numberOfAdults>
  </Room>
</RoomGroup>
<numberOfResults>1</numberOfResults>
<supplierCacheTolerance>MED_ENHANCED</supplierCacheTolerance>
```

I have created a list view form the response. I need to sort the list view by price and i have done that also. But what i need exactly is that I need to perform the sorting by a button on click, now i have done by default. I have my button in another activity and array adapter.  how can i call array adapter sorting method from this activity

Comment: please search the web  you have many tutorials on this

Comment: Harsh Dev Chandel, Could you please provide a link.. i searched a lot.. but failed...